# Android Lifecycle - how to ensure that one method is always called?

Tags: android

What must I do in order to ensure that the app is always initialised, even if the user or OS kills it?

```
public static void init(){/*some init and checks here*/}
```

if an `MyAlarmReceiver.onReceive()` or `MyBroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` is called by the OS... how to automatically call `init()` without putting it as the first statement in the `MyAlarmReceiver.onReceive()`, `MyBroadcastReceiver.onReceive()`, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that extends Application and put the statement in the onCreate method
Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

You can add a static block in your class, this code block will be executed when this class this loaded by ClassLoader, that means any usage of this class will cause the ClassLoader load this class into memory

```
public class Test extends BroadcastReceiver{
    static{
         //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: is it really a good idea to make assumption on when the class will be loaded by the class loader? if the initialization has no android dependencies it would be fine, but if it needs to be aware of life-cycle this would be a risky bet

Comment: yep, any static reference have a risk of memory leak, you need to pay attention to the GC can recycle the object reference by static field or not.

Comment: what I mean is, if you need to do android-unrelated initialization, the solution you're proposing would be fine. on the other hand if you need a Context in your initialization, how can you be sure that Application.onCreate had been called already?

Comment: but you see the question, init() is the static method, author just not want to add invoke statement

Comment: i think that the point is to find a solution to a problem, not blindly following a thought that might cause problems